# Javascript button to open new window on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have the following code, and I'm trying to make the button open in a new tab with the link generated, help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace("https://www.payjunction.com/trinity/quickshop/add_to_cart_snap.action?store=paymentbutton&description=INVOICE NO. " + $("#invoice_number").val() + "&need_to_tax=no&need_to_ship=no&price=" + $("#payment_amount").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">

<body> Enter your <b>Invoice Number</b> and <b>Payment Amount</b> below:
  <form id="form"> <input type="text" name="invoice_no" placeholder="Invoice Number" value="" id="invoice_number" required>
    <input type="text" name="payment_amount" placeholder="Payment Amount" value="" id="payment_amount" required>
    <button type="submit" id="button">Pay with Credit Card</button>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </form>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `target="_blank"` in the `<form>` tag?

Comment: and the issue is?

Comment: @ochi: *«I'm trying to make the button open in a new tab»*

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs behind [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). You can bind that to the button click, pass it the generated URL, and it will open it in a new tab/window.

i.e. in your case it would probably look like this:

```
$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open("https://www.payjunction.com/trinity/quickshop/add_to_cart_snap.action?store=paymentbutton&description=INVOICE NO. " + $("#invoice_number").val() + "&need_to_tax=no&need_to_ship=no&price=" + $("#payment_amount").val());
});
```